# Excel different formats of date how to sort in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a set of data and wish to do the analysis using Pandas,  but the problem is the date formats in the dataset are inconsistent. Even I had changed the date by format cells but still have some date stored as text.

[image: data_set]

The thing I get in Python: [image]

Comment: You need to correct your data import routine so that all the dates are "real" dates.  Then the numberformat will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` parameter, as follows:

```
# convert Date with different format strings
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m-%d-%y', errors='coerce')
```

Combine the results with [`.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['Date_combined'] = df['Date1'].combine_first(df['Date2'])
```

Then, you can sort the dates by:

```
df.sort_values(by='Date_combined')
```

### Demo

**Input:**

```
         Date
0  11/26/2013
1  11/26/2015
2   3/23/2014
3    08-02-13
4    08-02-15
5    09-02-13
6   1/22/2014
```

**Output:**

```
         Date      Date1      Date2 Date_combined
0  11/26/2013 2013-11-26        NaT    2013-11-26
1  11/26/2015 2015-11-26        NaT    2015-11-26
2   3/23/2014 2014-03-23        NaT    2014-03-23
3    08-02-13        NaT 2013-08-02    2013-08-02
4    08-02-15        NaT 2015-08-02    2015-08-02
5    09-02-13        NaT 2013-09-02    2013-09-02
6   1/22/2014 2014-01-22        NaT    2014-01-22
```